# What happened to Lyanna Mormont?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In the Corpse Reanimation Scene during the climax of S08E03 we see Lyanna Mormont open her eyes. At first I thought that this meant that she had survived the giant attack, but her eyes were not originally blue. Additionally, they are clearly not wight eyes; But they are almost, sort-of, close to being White Walker eyes, but without any of the glow or inhuman aspects.

Is their some explanation for these eyes? The scene was rather long, and incredibly close up, so presumably the eyes look exactly how the director wanted them to look.

[image: Eye Comparison]

Comment: They *are* wight eyes, it's clearly meant to represent that Lyanna was been raised from the dead by the Night King. i suspect this is more due to the lighting than any *difference* in color from what you consider "normal" wight eyes.

Comment: I'm 100% sure they are meant to be wight eyes. There's been some inconsistencies with how the eyes of wights and the eyes of white walkers look throughout the series. It's just a matter of different props/film lighting/director visions/effect specialists from episode to episode.

Comment: @Virusbomb Yes, sure. I could buy that. But her eyes are 100% different from all other wights raised in this singular episode as well. In similar lighting conditions, seconds before and seconds after Lyanna opened her eyes we see other wights, with eyes completely different from Lyanna but very similar to all other wights... An eye that is a featureless ball of softly glowing light blue is not really anything like Lyanna's eyes. And you could still be correct, but we are not talking about inconsistencies between episodes, but inconsistencies between adjacent shots in the same scene.

Comment: Hmm, OK, after watching this episode a few more times I am starting to see every ones point. The wight eyes showcased are extremely varied. Non of them that I saw other than Lyanna looked even somewhat human, but they definitely had a huge range. Not sure why they would do the worst job on the eyes with the most screen time. But she probably was just a run of the mill wight.

Comment: Rational thinking answers this question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

She's surely just a wight. It was during the sequence where all the recently dead rose, such as Edd and Qhono and those in the crypt, so I doubt Lyanna is any different.

Maybe it's due to the specific lighting in the scene, but afaik, White Walkers can only be created out of living beings, specifically by the Night King, and certainly not by being crushed to death by a wight giant.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the storyline, We know that the Night King can raise the dead. In the picture below the movie-maker shows a series of dead people being bought alive.

[image]

Lyanna Mormont:
I don't know how she survived the first hit when the giant hit her. Image below. The giant's fists are bigger than her body frame.

[image]
Considering the fact, that she was slammed to the ground from about 20ft high, there is a very low possibility for a 9-year-old to be alive.

(Brighter video) for reference.

If she was alive, the movie makers would have continued her storyline, but they didn't which means that she's a wight now.

Answer (score -3):

Upon a rewatch I started wondering about that too. I suspect that it has to do with her age - that just like Craster's sons she's young enough to be converted in a White Walker instead of merely a wight. I kinda wish we had been able to see zombie Lyanna fight.

Comment: Unlike Craster's sons, she's dead, so she can't be a White Walker, only a wight.
The same applied to Viserion.